# Префиксы в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка

Возможно ли в JS или JQuery использовать что-то вроде префиксов?

Что-то вроде такого:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(document.documentElement.clientWidth < 901) {
    $('.features-slider-1').slick({
      moz-prevArrow: '<button><img src=/img/str-left.png></button>',
      moz-nextArrow: '<button><img src=/img/str-right.png></button>'
    });
  }
});
```

Пример привёл условный. Нужно чтобы скрипт отображался только в определённых браузерах.

Comment: Может быть я не совсем правильно сформулировал вопрос... Мне нужно, что бы скрипт отображался только в определённых браузерах. Не спрашивайте "зачем?".

Comment: Вам, для начала, нужно определить браузер, один из примеров реализации https://stackoverflow.com/a/9851769/5724925

Comment: Я определил. Мне нужно для стандартного андроид браузера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В JS принят [CamelCase](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).
Поэтому - `mozJustDoIt`!

---

Но надо помнить что JS и CSS - немного разные поля деятельности и в JS, как правило, нет нужды делать несколько одинаковых свойств с префиксами.